# Расширение блока при focus

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Как на jQuery сделать, чтобы когда нажимаешь на `<input>` блок плавно расширялся?
Я вообще jQ не знаю, вот что смог сделать:

```
    $(function(){
    $('.sinp').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('width', '250px');
    });
});
```

Тут input'у присвоен класс .sinp. По идее осталось сделать плавно и чтобы при "отводке" (outfocus или как там) обратно возвращалось к значению в css  файле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("input").focus(function(){
        $(this).animate({ width:"500px"}, 1000);
    }).blur(function(){
        $(this).animate({ width:"250px"}, 500);
    });
});
```

Обратно возвращается: http://jsfiddle.net/bq2LC/1.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ не много не подходит, так как не является кросбраузерным, но он тоже может иметь право существования:

**CSS3** http://jsfiddle.net/bq2LC/3/

```
input {            
    width: 250px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s leaner;
    -o-transition: width 1s leaner;
    -ms-transition: width 1s leaner;
    -moz-transition: width 1s leaner;
}
input:focus {
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.sinp').focus(function() {
        $(this).animate({width: "250px"}, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: стоп. А обратно не возвращается..

Comment: а обратно это другое событие blur, http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F ,читайте раздел события формы